# R - replace variable with a specific values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I want to replace several variables by 1 in a dataset:

```
data(iris)

put_1 <- function(x){ x = 1}

iris %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), funs(put_1)) %>% 
   head()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5            1           1  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0            1           1  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2            1           1  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1            1           1  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6            1           1  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9            1           1  setosa
```

**Question : Is there a way to do the same without declaring a function before ?**

I tried things like :

- `mutate_at(vars(...), funs(function(x){ x <- 1 }))`
- `mutate_at(vars(...), funs(~ 1 }))`
- `mutate_at(vars(...), funs(~ . = 1 }))`

without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), ~ 1)`

Comment: i didn't know it is not necessary to use `funs()`. Thank you.

Comment: `funs()` is only needed when applying more than one function. It's also being soft-deprecated in favor of just supplying a list of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is from **@josemz**

```
iris %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), ~ 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the times when `=` and `<-` don't work the same

```
> iris%>%mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length,Petal.Width),funs(.<-1))%>%head()
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5            1           1  setosa
2          4.9         3.0            1           1  setosa
3          4.7         3.2            1           1  setosa
4          4.6         3.1            1           1  setosa
5          5.0         3.6            1           1  setosa
6          5.4         3.9            1           1  setosa
```

And

```
> iris%>%mutate_at(vars(Petal.Length,Petal.Width),funs(.=1))%>%head()
Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```